# Set default permissions to files in folders on VPS with Ubuntu

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, permissions

I know this probably is a subject many other places as well, but I have tried many of the things written in other posts, and still no luck.

I am running a Ubuntu VPS with apache, ftp and php.
My goal: Every time I add an image to a folder the image should be accessible for the public.  I have tried different chmod-commands but still no luck.
I want each image to have access rights: rwxrwxrwx, but as default when I upload them to the the folder through Filezilla they end up with access rights rwx-------.

I hope also I have given enough information. Please comment below if not, and I will provide as fast as possible. ( I am kind of new to the game, sorry about that)

Answer (score -1):

You can change the default permission in your ftp server. I don't know which ftp server you're using? Or you can build a script that changes the permissions and execute this.